# Can't see objects properly in Material Preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine, image

For business reasons I found myself having to install Blender on my office computer to view 3D files.
Now it is no longer necessary but this program and its potential intrigued me a lot, so I proceeded to install it on my home computer.
Once installed I started to see some tutorials on the web and when I got to coloring objects (or assigning materials) I ran into a problem.
Basically once I create the material to assign to the object and its "Base Color" if I go to the "Preview Mode" window I get a completely dark object.
At first I thought I had something wrong with my custom object but I also tested the startup cube and I get the same result.

[image: Material Preview]

Rendering the final image with Eevee I get the following image.
[image: Eevee final rendering]

Instead if I try to render with Cycles I get the right image, but I have read that Cycles doesn't work well with AMD graphic cards, and it is also slow.
[image: Cycles Final rendering]

My hardware is as follows:
Motherboard: MSI B450 Gaming Plus Max
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600X
GPU: XFX AMD RX580
RAM: Corsair Vengeance 2x8GB 3200MHz C16

AMD drivers are the latest recommended, so 20.11.2
The version of blender I installed is 2.91.0

Please tell me if I was exhaustive with the explanation of the problem or you need more details.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's an issue with the latest AMD Adrenalin drivers - happening to tons of people. Roll back to an earlier driver version.

Comment: It works!
Thank you very much, I have uninstalled the drivers and installed the 20.Q4 for tests and they work properly.